# MvvmCross: How do I style Spinner (MvxSpinner)?

Tags: android, xamarin, spinner, mvvmcross, mvxspinner

So, the question is simple. How do I apply styling for MvxSpinner.

There is plenty of answers regarding to styling a common Spinner, but most of them refer to this lines of code:

```
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(SupportActionBar.ThemedContext, Resource.Layout.event_selector, events);
  adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(global::Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);

_eventSelector.Adapter = adapter;
```

However, I am not sure how to handle that in case of MvxSpinner. It probably uses some MvvmCross-specific own adapter. My binding is as follows:

```
 <Mvx.MvxSpinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lstCategoryGroups"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource CategoryGroups; SelectedItem CategoryGroupdSelected"
     />
```

Any ideas?
Both approaches: as styling the specific spinner element on the page as setting common style for any spinner. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can change the layout of the spinner (hence the style) directly in axml via two attributes:

- `local:MvxItemTemplate`: Sets the layout of the selected item.
- `local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate`: Sets the layout of each item in the dropdown

So given a ViewModel with a collection `CategoryGroups` and the `SelectedCategoryGroup`, i.e.:

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    ...

    public ObservableCollection<CategoryGroup> CategoryGroups { get; set; }

    public CategoryGroup CategoryGroupdSelected { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

and the `CategoryGroup` class:

```
public class CategoryGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can bind the collection to a spinner like this:

```
<MvxSpinner
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:theme="@style/Spinner"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/my_spinner_item"
    local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/my_spinner_dropdown_item"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource CategoryGroups; SelectedItem CategoryGroupdSelected" />
```

and in each template you define the layout/style of the item. Take into account that in the templates their `DataContext` is an item (in this case a `CategoryGroup`). In my example, I want to display the `Name` of each `CategoryGroup` then I just need a `TextView` and bind its `Text` property to the `Name` of the `CategoryGroup`, i.e. the item's `DataContext`:

my_spinner_item.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    local:MvxBind="Text Name" />
```

my_spinner_dropdown_item.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    local:MvxBind="Text Name" />
```

---

Now if you want all of your spinner to have the same templates you can just set a style with those attributes or you can inherit `MvxSpinner` and set the templates programmatically.

Apart from that if you want to use one of each template and not create one per each different binding you could have a base class `BaseItemViewModel`  with an `abstract` property named `Description` and use that to bind in the `View`. So that in your VMs you always inherit from `BaseItemViewModel` and override `Description` property to have the value you want to display.

```
public abstract class BaseItemViewModel : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public abstract string Description { get; }
}
```

Another way is to have a `WrappedItemViewModel` where you pass the object `T` you want to be in the spinner and a `Func<T, string>` that returns what the spinner displays (the description) and you have a `Description` property that just invokes the `Func<T, string>`. This way has the advantage that it doesn't make you inherit always from a VM and you can wrap almost any object in it adding the behaviour to be in a Spinner.

```
public class WrappedItemViewModel<T> : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly Func<T, string> descriptionFunc;

    public WrappedItemViewModel(T item, Func<T, string> descriptionFunc)
    {
         this.MyItem = item;
         this.descriptionFunc = descriptionFunc;
    }

    public T MyItem { get; }

    public string Description => this.descriptionFunc.Invoke(this.MyItem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, could you also provide (possibly with update in the answer) details of the my_spinner_item template. I mean, for example, the TextView should be also bound to data in some way. I guess, it won't work without additional manipulations? (Especially, if I want that to be generic template for any Spinner).

Comment: @Agat there I've updated the answer with some ways to achieve what you want. HIH

Comment: That's still not fully clear regarding to ItemViewModel and TextValue property to bound. Still cannot get it to work. Could you clarify on that?
So, let's say, if I have MyCurrentViewViewModel with a set of Products (simple strings or Product class with own properties, for instance), and also a ProductSelected property. So, I can't catch what's the TextValue property in all that routine.

Comment: I've updated the answer taking the `CategoryGroups` of your question. To your case of `Products`, `TextValue` would be a property inside a `Product`. I hope now it's clearer.